# Convert two tables into single table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two tables:

```
+-------------+--------+      +----+-------+
| employee_id | val_id |      | id | value |
+-------------+--------+      +----+-------+
|         123 |      1 |      |  1 |     A |
+-------------+--------+      +----+-------+
|         123 |      2 |      |  2 |     B |
+-------------+--------+      +----+-------+
|         123 |      3 |      |  3 |     C |
+-------------+--------+      +----+-------+
```

Expected result

```
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+ 
| employee_id | val_1 | val_2 | val_3 | ...
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+ 
|         123 |     A |     B |     C |
```

Could you help me please

Comment: You should check `Join` and `Pivot`.

Comment: Check out the PIVOT command http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Are you wanting to combine the physical two tables or are you wanting a query with results as expected?

Comment: give me the sql queries for this result

Comment: Are there are known number of val_n columns?  If so, pivot.

Comment: Looks like you made more effort with ascii art than asking a proper question. Consider re-writing if you are looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

1. CREATE value column in first table
2. UPDATE 'value' column by update clause (you can use subselect for selecting value)
3. DROP val_id column
4. DROP second table

how big are tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use join and pivot .This will gives the required result

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT employeeID,'val_'+CAST(a.val_id AS VARCHAR(2)) val_id ,value 
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.val_id=b.val_id
) AS ss
PIVOT
(
    MAX(value)
    FOR [val_id] IN ([val_1],[val_2],[val_3])
)AS pivott
```